# DosBox / Win10 file/folder issues, and batch files

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

SITUATION:
I have DOSBox (ver reports DOS 5.00) running under Windows10.  "DOS" herein refers only to the DOSBox "guest" environment.  I created a subdir called "bulk" on the Windows side, and I can mount it with
`mount c "c:\...\bulk"`
SYMPTOMS:

Folders: If I create a folder from within Windows, I can see it in DOS.  If I create a folder within DOS, I cannot see it in Windows.

Files: Within DOS I can:
`echo This will work > foo.txt`
This silently succeeds.
The file will be visible (and persistent across sessions) from within DOS, but not from within Windows -- regardless of which system (Win or DOS) created the folder.
But I can not:
`echo This will not work > foo.bat`
This fails with an indicator, as:
`C:\>echo This will not work > foo2.bat
This will not work
C:\>`
Instead, the echo'd content has been redirected to the screen (in DOS), and an error message accumulates (something redirected to stderr or stdout) in the DOSBox console (not in the DOS environment).

Batch Files in particular:
No matter what, I cannot create a batch file from within DOS, not even in the built-in Z:\ directory (which is not otherwise visible to the Windows file system).

Windws as myself: I can create batch files anf folders all day long 
SUSPICION:
I suspect that this is a file system permissions clash, but with the finnickiness about batch files, I don't know where it's coming from.
If you know of a Windows etting about batch file creation in particular, I'm all ears.  But that may not be the issue, so don't let me guess too hard about the solution.
-- Oh, I just discovered the problem.  I'll post an answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

CULPRIT: The afore-mentioned c:...\bulk folder elided an important (as it turns out) fact:  The full path was something like c:\Program Files(x86)\DOSBox\bulk, and some of you may already see the problem.  "Program Files" folders have restrictions on them.
DOSBox (at least version 0.74-2) prefers to install to that directory.

SOLUTION: I relocated .\bulk to a ~\Documents\Retro\bulk, which fixed the issue.  Just had to update the mount parameter in the ini/config file.  I will see if I can re-install the whole mess to my preferred ~\Documents\RunFromHere.  This works out of the box for simple programs, and so far I have not run into any issues with app permissions just because a given app isn't sitting in Program Files.
We'll see.